# What does "augment" mean when asking how likely "turnt" is to replace or augment "turned"?

Tags: meaning

This [link](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/does-past-tense-turnt-have-a-future/) asks the question of how likely is turnt likely to replace or augment turned.

The definition of augment (Indo-European) is a syllable added to the beginning of the word in certain Indo-European languages.

So how does "turnt" augment "turned" based on the link? Thank you!

Comment: Suprisingly, the article does not mention **burnt/burned** or **learnt/learned**. "How likely?" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @WeatherVane This question is about the usage of augment in the question posed by Daily Writing Tips as I read it.

Comment: [Augment has more meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/augment) than just the one you asserted. Have you checked the other meanings to see if they make sense for that context?

Answer (score 1):

As ColleenV hinted, "augment" has other meanings than that somewhat obscure one — which can't apply, if you reflect on it, because it's a noun rather than a verb as used in the quoted sentence.

In this case "augment" would mean "be added to, without replacing". In other words, perhaps "turnt" will become an alternative past participle of "turn", either in free variation with "turned" or serving different purposes (adjective vs. past tense, for example).

Comment: People have said 'turnt' for centuries in the west of England.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Interesting. Anyhow, my answer doesn't comment on the likelihood of this happening.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - and also in Scots dialect.

Comment: I find _augment_ an extremely odd choice of word here: I would expect _supplement_.

Comment: @ColinFine I find there are few collocations in which it's the best or most likely choice, but I don't find this one particularly odd, relatively speaking.